How to open an USB's encrypted /boot automatically
My situation is a bit unique:
The scenario ~
I have successfully encrypted my root partition and boot partitions. My boot partition lies on my usb along with the /boot/efi on a separate unencrypted partition on the usb. I use grub and my system works fine as is. But, I would love to skip the boot password (since i will keep my usb secure) and really just encrypted the /boot partition as a just in case measure. So, I have a keyfile already linked to the /boot partition and its well hidden and disguised so nobody can assume its there on the /boot/efi unencrypted partition within the usb.
With all that said, how can i get grub to use this keyfile to decrypt the boot partition at boot? (I saw a tutorial that demonstrates something similar to this om the arch wiki dm-crypt page, but its methods didn't work because they could be outdated?)
Or is there a better method of securing my boot usb to be suggested? I even tried to just use veracrypt hidden volumes on linux with little success.

I guess it's technically possible but not directly supported. Requires grub 2.12 and a custom core.img with embedded config that does cryptomount with keyfile (recent new feature). Is it worth all this effort for a security by obscurity measure? It won't be difficult to find out how Grub obtains the key.

Interesting. Well as i say my boot is on a usb along with the /efi so if everything is encrypted, if i understand correctly, you can still trave grub back to a specific keyfile granted you have my USB and My Root disk. Not just one or the other since both are needed to work? If this is the case ~ i dont presume ill and will never be put in a situation whereas both are confiscated together. So i can afford such risk

Is it possible to find a tutorial outh there that demonstrates this method? I've had terrible luck myself

There are some discussions about core.img customizations on the grub mailing lists. I'm not sure if there is a dedicated guide. It's not very straightforward. Basically Grubs cryptodisk encrypted /boot magic is in grub-install and you want to customize it but it's hardcoded there so you can't use it directly. I could probably write an answer, but it would not be 100% what you described in your question, just somewhat similar and you adapt it yourself.

Note: This answer focuses on making GRUB use a password or keyfile to decrypt /boot automatically. It does not cover anything else, like USB sticks, two-factor security, or whatever. You'll have to adapt it on your own.
You need GRUB cryptomount command with support for passwords or keyfiles.
You can check it directly in the Grub console:
grub> insmod cryptodisk
grub> help cryptomount
Usage: cryptomount [ [-p password] | [-k keyfile …
                      ^^^^^^^         ^^^^^^

Or in the terminal:
$ strings {/boot,/usr/lib}/grub/*/cryptodisk.mod | grep keyfile
[ [-p password] | [-k keyfile …

If keyfiles are not supported, update GRUB first (to 2.12 or newer).

The starting point is to encrypt /boot the standard Grub way. This is described in almost every wiki, to re-hash:

use LUKS with --pbkdf=pbkdf2 (argon2 not supported by GRUB yet) and optionally also with --pbkdf-force-iterations=1024 or similar to reduce iteration counts (GRUB is very slow)
use a passphrase with high entropy (XKCD style). Note that GRUB doesn't support very large keyfiles either.
set GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK=y in /etc/default/grub
run grub-install…

And the result should be something like this:
Welcome to GRUB!

Enter passphrase for …: _


Now, how to automate it for unattended boot?
Officially this is not supported, so you have to pull a rabbit out of the hat.
This is not straightforward since the GRUB_ENABLE_CRYPTODISK behavior is hardcoded in grub-install. Thankfully you can see a bit of what it is doing if you run with the --verbose option. This produces a LOT of output, but really interesting are two lines:

grub-install: info: grub-mkimage --directory '/usr/lib/grub/i386-pc' --prefix '(cryptouuid/1bf1…)/grub' --output '/boot/grub/i386-pc/core.img' --format 'i386-pc' --compression 'auto' --config '/boot/grub/i386-pc/load.cfg' … 'cryptodisk' 'luks2' ….
grub-install: info: grub-bios-setup  --verbose     --directory='/boot/grub/i386-pc' --device-map='/boot/grub/device.map' '/dev/sdx'.

The first line creates GRUB's core.img. The second line installs it to the target device.
In EFI mode, it looks a bit different:

grub-install: info: grub-mkimage --directory '/usr/lib/grub/x86_64-efi' --prefix '(cryptouuid/1bf1…)/grub' --output '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi' --format 'x86_64-efi' --compression 'auto' --config '/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/load.cfg' … 'cryptodisk' 'luks2' ….
grub-install: info: copying `/boot/grub/x86_64-efi/core.efi' -> `/boot/efi/EFI/arch/grubx64.efi'.

So what is happening here?
GRUB's utilities happen to be split into multiple separate binaries. grub-install installs GRUB, grub-mkimage generates a core.img / core.efi, grub-bios-setup embeds the core.img in a BIOS environment (or it's copied over in the EFI case), etc.
Partly due to this split utility concept, grub-install generates some temporary files, to be used by the next utility in a multiple step process.
In both cases, it embeds a load.cfg which looks like this:
cryptomount -u 1bf1…

All it does is run cryptomount with -u uuid option. This is where you want to add -k keyfile option, or -p password if you prefer.

So all we have to do is edit this load.cfg file, right? Unfortunately, not. GRUB does not use this file when booting (it's encrypted, remember?); grub-install does not respect edits to this file; it rewrites it every time. If you try to cheat and write-protect it, you even get a segfault…
So we could make a wrapper around grub-mkimage, right? Unfortunately, also not. While the debug message makes it sounds like grub-install executes grub-mkimage, that actually never happens. The GRUB utilities are structured in such a way that these calls happen internally. You can delete grub-mkimage altogether and grub-install still works fine, even though it uses grub-mkimage…
So how do we put the fly in the soup?
The trick is to run grub-install with --verbose, extract those two lines from it, then re-run these two commands yourself (with your own load.cfg).
grub-install does the heavy lifting: it detects your configuration, builds a list of required GRUB modules, detects UUIDs, and constructs the correct load.cfg and grub-mkimage command line, and finally embeds everything.
You take it away, you build a custom core.img, and install it.

Some pitfalls: grub-install is unaware that you're going to load a keyfile from some other partition and filesystem. You might have to embed additional GRUB modules into core.img to support this, which can be done with grub-install --modules="…" (space separated list of missing modules).
If you wish to write a more elaborate load.cfg you can attempt to do so, but not everything works; this config still runs in limited feature mode. Switch to GRUB normal mode only happens after you decrypted /boot.
It's easy to break GRUB (and more) this way. Have another boot stick ready for emergency booting. You could also put your custom grub.efi under a separate name and register it with efibootmgr (also shown in grub-install --verbose). That way, you can select the official/manual vs. your custom/automated one in the efi boot menu.

TL;DR:

run grub-install with --verbose and keep its output (shell redirect or dedicated terminal window)
edit load.cfg, e.g. add -p mysecretpassword or -k (hd0,gpt1)/keyfile or the like to the cryptmount command (test these commands on the grub shell beforehand)
run grub-mkimage (as shown by grub-install --verbose)
run grub-bios-setup or copy the core.efi file (as shown by grub-install --verbose)

And if you've done it correctly, GRUB will decrypt /boot completely without user interaction:
Welcome to GRUB!

Slot "0" opened


PS: Keep in mind, whatever you put into core.img is not a big secret.
$ binwalk --lzma --extract core.img
DECIMAL       HEXADECIMAL     DESCRIPTION
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3344          0xD10           Raw LZMA compression stream, properties: 0x5D [pb: 2, lp: 0, lc: 0], dictionary size: 33554432
$ strings _core.img.extracted/D10 | grep cryptomount
cryptomount
cryptomount -u … -p MyNotVerySecretPassword

So in case of password, or keyfile on the same device, this is no more than simple obfuscation.
Furthermore, GRUB itself reveals the volume key on the GRUB shell:
grub> cat (proc)/luks_script
luks2_mount … aes-xts-plain64 e7385a067a6e8b…


Does it make sense to have a standalone GRUB at the beginning that then decrypts the other boot partition to load grub and .., or is that nonsense? I’ve always only encrypted the system partition. Is it more secure if the boot partition is also encrypted? What do you think?

Sure, you can try it. You can also encrypt kernel+initramfs this way. A minimal kernel+initramfs which embeds an encrypted one and the means to decrypt&kexec it. It can be done. Is it worth the effort, though…? In a generic install, /boot, kernel, initramfs should not hold any personal data worth encrypting. I'm okay leaving those unencrypted. I only wrote this answer because I claimed it was possible… there might be better ways to do it (like, just patch grub-install to use your config, no shenanigans).

The answer is still very insightful; I’ve learned something new again +1 btw
